# HTTPS configuration for AWS EBS

Tags: ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, whm

I am facing a problem every time developing a backend and deploying it on EBS ( AWS Elastic Bean Stalk)

What I have:
A node.js backend hosted on EBS with load balancer set to min:1 max:1 (Because no money).
EBS link : http://crm-env.eba-tud935mv.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/v1
A subdomain with SSLcertificate issued by CPanel : https://crmbackened.metablocktechnologies.io/

The problem: how to route this subdomain to the EBS link with HTTPS
The reason : cookies are not allowed on non-HTTPS requests

let me now if more details are required.

I am at the end of my experience in this matter. Kindly help.

What I tried:
created a ACM(AWS cert. manager)  public certificate for  crmbackened.metablocktechnologies.io ( which was useless as that subdomain already had HTTPS)
added a load balancer and added the certificate which I created above to the load balancer. Not sure why this is incorrect.
Created a route 53 hosted zone for  metablocktechnologies.io added a A Record with name = crmbackened.metablocktechnologies.io and alias to my EBS-env

Answer (score 1):

You can use Route53 and ACM to secure your ESB with HTTPS.
Firstly, delegate your subdomain 'crmbackend.metablocktechnologies.io' to Route53 using NS records. Next, create an ACM (AWS Certificate Manager) and validate it using CNAME. Once validated, point your ESB to your subdomain in Route53 using A record alias or CNAME. This way, you'll have secure and encrypted communication for your ESB.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/dns-validation.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html

Hope this can help you. Let me know if you have any other questions or if you need another solution.